# nodemon not watching for changes in tsx files

Tags: nodemon

I'm trying to test my typescript react app, and I have nodemon running jasmine tests on `.ts` files, but I can't get `.tsx` to trigger the watch action.

My package.json has a fairly simple

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jasmine-ts **/*.spec.ts*",
"test-watch": "nodemon -e ts -w ./ -x npm run test",
```

I thought the `*` at the end of the `spec.ts*` would tell nodemon to re-run on `.ts` as well as `.tsx` but that doesn't seem to work.

Neither does `.tsx?`

Comment: the `-e` argument tells nodemon to watch for `ts` files, the `-w` on the root directory, and then run the `npm run test` script. Seems nodemon is only triggering the script if a ts file changes. Should not you add the wildcard after the `-e` ?

Comment: thanks @KevinAmiranoff, I tried that, I thought -e was running my typescript compiler. It didn't work with `-e ts*` if that's what you were thinking

Answer (score 7):

turns out the correct way to write this for nodemon is
`"test-watch": "nodemon -e ts,tsx -w ./ -x npm run test",`